# NAS ForceDirectories

Tags: delphi, nas, delphi-10-seattle

I cannot seem to be able to call `ForceDirectories()` on a NAS partition on Windows 10 64-bit.

I can create a folder on the NAS using Windows Explorer just fine.

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  tempDir: String;
begin
  tempDir := 'z:\ttt\ttttest';
  if NOT DirectoryExists(tempDir) then
    if System.SysUtils.ForceDirectories(tempDir) then
      ShowMessage('Dir: ' + tempDir + ' Forced alright')
    else
      ShowMessage('Dir: ' + tempDir + ' Force FAILED with error : '+ IntToStr(GetLastError));
end;
```

`Z:` is the Western Digital Network Attached Storage which works fine in all other respects.

The code returns error 3 every time.

Same code works correctly on local drives.

Comment: Works fine for me. Probably a mapping for permission issue locally. One wonders if you are running delphi ide as admin.

Comment: Also, I trust you know what 3 means here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Error 3 is `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND`.  Drive letter mappings are per-user, so chances are that the `Z:` drive does not exist for the user account that is running your app. Also, `ForceDirectories()` checks if the directory exists before creating it, so you don't need to call `DirectoryExists()` manually.

Comment: Still not working. There must be something basically wrong. Every other tool I use manages to create and access folders on the NAS fine (Directory Opus, File Explorer, MS Word, NotePad++) all of them.
Any other ideas?

Comment: I do run Delphi as an administrator and have tested to make sure the app runs under my administrator user.

Comment: That's your problem. You are running the process in a context without the drive mapped. As a rule, running delphi elevated is a terrible idea. Stop it.

Answer (score 0):

You are running your IDE as admin. That means that your process also runs as admin. And it seem that when run as admin, the drive mapping to the NAS drive is not available.

My advice is not to run your IDE as admin.

Comment: Tried it both ways as admin and not admin. Nothing works.
Going to junk this project.